# Query for specific taxonomy that executes a particular loop depending on volume of posts?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, terms, loop

Is it possible to create a special wp query that looks to see how many posts exist in a specific taxonomy, or taxonomy term, and executes a particular loop depending on the volume of posts?

My idea behind this is - 
**Id like to be able to show particular CPT content in a different styled format depending on how many of those posts exist**.

For example: 
*Lets say the **taxonomy "product categories"** only contains about **2 posts** listed with **child terms** that exist in that taxonomy **rather then something like 20**...

Well what Id like to do is list those products in a larger style via CSS instead of having to default on the more consolidated styling for when their are a larger volume of products.*

Can this be done, and if so how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check the total number of posts found:

```
if($your_query->found_posts > 20) ...
```

and decide how do you want your mark-up to be.

If want to see how many products are associated with a certain product_category term, use [get_term()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term) and check out the 'count' property

Comment: Hey thank you for the response, could you possibly extrapolate on that a bit with a more detailed example? Id greatly appreciate it!

Comment: Would this be before the loop or after the loop has begun?

Comment: I'm assuming you need it before the loop. Is this the main query, or a custom query? You should post the entire code related to your question

Comment: It needs to be achieved via WP's taxonomy templates if thats possible but I wasn't sure of that being a possibility yet hence my post, so ive still yet to write the code. (or at least I believe what Im trying to achieve can only work with those particular templates??....if this can actually work with a custom page template instead I was unaware of that since I need to be able to view CPT's sorted by custom tax terms)

Comment: If it will help, I can mock something up that will at least show you what Im trying to do, just let me know.

Comment: ok, then you would use `$wp_query->found_posts` to get that number. Post the template code...

Comment: Ok, lemme work something up and I'll report back in a bit, thanks for the help.